# Dynamic Image reference in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura

Trying to set image name from attribute , For dynamic load. Is there any other way ?

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">
   <aura:attribute name="imageName" type="String" access="global" default="{!$Resource.abd}"/>
   <div class="slds-p-top_medium slds-clearfix">
      <div class="slds-float_left">
         <!-- Display company logo --> 
         <h2>
          <img src="{!$Resource+v.imageName}"/>   
          </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-float_right" style="position:relative;">
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.screenHelpText ne null}">
            <!-- If the screen has help text, display an info icon in the header.
                 On hover, display the screen's help text -->
            <lightning:helptext content="{!v.screenHelpText}" />
         </aura:if>
      </div>
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can achieve it through Lightning Component 'Controller':

1. Collect all the images, make a zip folder.
2. Collect all the images, make a zip folder.
3. Upload it to the static resource.
4. Use Images in dynamic reference.

Follow the below controller code :

```
({
    profileUrl: function(component) {
        var profileUrl1 = $A.get('$Resource.yourGraphics') + '/images/avatar1.jpg';
        var profileUrl2 = $A.get('$Resource.yourGraphics') + '/images/avatar2.jpg';
        var profileUrl3 = $A.get('$Resource.yourGraphics') + '/images/avatar3.jpg';

        alert("Profile URL 1: " + profUrl1);
        alert("Profile URL 2: " + profUrl2);
        alert("Profile URL 3: " + profUrl3);
    }
})
```

Comment: This Scenario and solution I am already aware about I do want to add a path rather then being name itself. Although looks according to SFDC standard Docs its not possible